# Events of View are not fireing

Tags: backbone.js

I am using the following view. The problem is the click event of #likeCar is not beeing fired. What I am doing wrong here?

```
window.LikeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #likeCar":"likeCar"
    },

    initialize : function(){
        this.el = $("#liker");
        this.template = _.template($('#like-template').html());
        //_.bindAll(this,"render");
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    },

    render : function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    likeCar : function(e) {
        console.log("like car")
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="like-template">
<a id="likeCar" class="btn btn-mini" href="#">Like</a>
```

Comment: How often is this view being used?  your template reads as if it will be created only once because the item has an id.  If you create more than one of these on a page, I'm sure strange things will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including this line in your view definition:

```
el: $('#liker')
```

Instead of initializing it in the initialize method.

Seems to work in the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xqREW/6/

Comment: Backbone docs don't read this way. The events should be bound to the views root node to delegate handling of events for child nodes http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents